# How to style text field?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Hence i finished all in my app. But i need to style my text field.This is my label and text fields are looking now:

[image]

**Needed:**

I need to style my label and text field like this.In single with below one line like this

[image]

I used some  textfield background image,but its showing only for textfield.How to do like this.please some body give some solution for that.I am new to ios.This breaking my head
Thanks in advance @!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few different options. A barebones approach could be to:

Create the horizontal line via UIView

```
UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y w,h)];
horizontalLine.backgroundcolor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Create the textfield with no border:

```
[yourTextField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[yourTextField setNeedsDisplay];
```

For something like this you can probably get away with doing it all in interface builder, which will make setting up your constraints a bit easier.

Comment: To create `UIView` can i use storyboard to make my X,Y,W,H. And when i place my textfield it should with no border (this also can i in storyboard)..

Comment: Yes, you can do all of this through interface builder. You will want to navigate to the inspector to change these properties.

Answer (score 1):

Add new view below each label (set height and background color to fit your needs), remove borders from textfields and that's it. You can change text color in xcode builder.

Comment: sorry i dint get you. have to add view on below each label and resize it with that single line.And remove  borders from my text field...is it correct ? or any other thing